# SQL query - How to exclude a record from another table

Tags: sql

Here’s the scenario:
I have 3 tables named tblSalesOrder, tblAcccountExecSummary and

**tblAccountExecStatus**
[image: tblAccountExecStatus]

Joined by ‘sales_id’ from tblSalesOrder and ‘id’ from tblAccountExecSummary, it is used for displaying in my program.

tblAccountExecSummary may have more than 1 account executives, 3 at max.

In the above example, the joined tables have 2 account executives for 1 sales order.

**tblAccountExecStatus**
[image: tblAccountExecStatus]

I only want display the joined table that has the account executive’s status of ‘2’ only. Meaning It would exclude the records if the sales order record has at least one account executive's status of ‘1’.

I'm looking for the right query for this and still I haven't got it yet. I really appreciate your help.

It would result to displaying all the data of tblSalesOrder

Comment: Use `not exists` in the where clause.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: either use "not exists" or "EXCEPT" or "NOT IN"

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: In an inner query, prepare all summary entries with an `account_executive` with status `1`. Let's call this inner query `summwith1`. Then, in the outer query, return those summary entries which's `id` is not contained in the ids of `sumwith1`.

```
select * from tblAccountExecSummary summary
where not exists
  (select 1 from tblAccountExecStatus status join tblAccountExecSummary sumwith1 on status.account_executive = sumwith1.account_executive
   where status.status = 1
     and sumwith1.id = summary.id
  )
```